# Find All Words Containing a String From a .txt Document

Tags: powershell, text

I'm cleaning up a few dozen old files, and pulling them into one format. I've extracted the headers for each of the sources to a text (.txt) file, and need to identify the different wording for similar column names.

To do this, I need to be able to identify common words in the headers. For example, I need to identify all column names that might be "firstname", "1stname", "first_name", "f_name", etc, etc, etc.

What PowerShell syntax would I use to find all words containing the string "**name"** (e.g. "First_**Name**"), and extract that entire word to a separate text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the content of the file into individual words, then select the words containing the particular string:

```
(Get-Content 'input.txt') -split '\s+' -match 'name'
```